# View Adwords Quality Score in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I have an Adwords account linked to a Google Analytics account and I am wondering is there a way to view or import the keyword quality score from Adwords to be viewed in Analytics?

Or would this have to be pulled from the Adwords API and joined to Analytics data separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword Quality Score cannot be directly imported to/viewed in Analytics. It is provided as a metric after the fact, but not a current state/output that you could append as a UTM variable.

Joining the Adwords Data to Analytics after the fact would be flawed too, as Quality Score is fluid (recalculated often).  Unless you are pulling and tracking Quality Score Data multiple times daily, you will find inaccuracies. If you take the keyword data for the last 30 days in Analytics and then pulled your Keyword Quality scores and married that data, you would be projecting the the Keyword Quality Score from the single moment in time that you pulled the data onto the previous 30 days of performance.  This is problematic because the Keyword Quality Score could have been much higher or lower for the majority of the 30 day date range.

Answer (score 0):

We currently manually download QS data via Adwords Editor on a weekly basis. It isn't an ideal situation but it does give us visibility over the account over time.